MQTT describe function outside the handler
I am working on MQTT
https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/mqtt-js-tutorial#mqtt-js-api-introduction
This is how i connect.
const client = mqtt.connect(host, optionsMQTT);

client.on('connect', function (connack) {
    console.log('Connected')
    console.log(connack)
});

Is it possible instead of passing this full function as parameter i only pass the name of the function :--
function (connack) {
    console.log('Connected')
    console.log(connack)
}

How to pass only the name of the function instead of full function and make it work ?

What have you tried and how didn't it work?

The following should work:
const client = mqtt.connect(host, optionsMQTT);

function connactFunc (connack) {
    console.log('Connected')
    console.log(connack)
}

client.on('connect', connactFunc);

